# Github Maven Packages can't be found in ORG

Tags: maven, gradle, github, github-package-registry

I'm trying to use Github packages as a maven repository.

When I point directly to a repo like this :

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/ORG/REPO")
        credentials {
            username = 'some-user'
            password = 'github-token-with-repo-scope'
        }
    }
}
```

And pulling the dependency like this:

```
dependencies{
    implementation 'groupId:artifcatId:1.0.0-snapshot'
}
```

It works.

But if I don't want to limit maven url to specific repo , and use ORG url directly

```
url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/ORG')
```

It won't find the same artifcat saying:

```
Could not find groupId:artifcatId:1.0.0-snapshot.
```

I have tried adding REPO name to dependency declaration

```
dependencies{
    implementation 'REPO:groupId:artifcatId:1.0.0-snapshot'
}
```

It still wont work.

Anyone has a clue how to use ORG url as a MAVEN REPOSITORY , instead of adding multiple urls to each repo (and multiplying the login calls etc... )

Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, you need to pass an access token in order to access the GitHub Package Registry: https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-packages

Comment: @Edric I do pass one, as you can see from first block of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer from github support that they have fixed that issue :)

> Hi Mark,
> Sorry about the delay in getting back to you! I've been working through some tickets that were left on-hold.

> This issue has now been fixed!

> You can't use https://maven.pkg.github.com/ORG, but you can use the following URL for normal and SNAPSHOT versions.

> `url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/ORG/*")`

> We'd like to have allowed https://maven.pkg.github.com/ORG, but there would have been no way to distinguish between the groupId and repo name

> Regards,
> Jamie.

P.S. Thanks to Jamie for the update :)